# 3 relation how database should look and how to create queries wtih Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, database-design, laravel-5

I have 3 relations:

`project` can have many `tasks` and `tast` have one `project`

`user` can have many `tasks` and `task` can have many `users`

`user` can have many `projects` and `project` can have many `users` --> this relation I already have in pivot table `project_user`

How other tables should look like and how can I query them to take all `tasks` for current logged user and some project id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table **task** should have "foreign key" **project_id**. Then you can find all tasks associated to one project.

You should have a table for linking users and tasks, like **user_task** with two fields : **user_id**/**task_i**d

You already have project_user for the last part.

To query them :
To get all project tasks

```
SELECT * FROM task WHERE project_id = {project_id}
```

Get all tasks for a user :

```
SELECT DISTINCT task.*
FROM user_task
INNER JOIN task ON task.id = user_task.task_id
WHERE user_task.user_id = {user_id}
```

Get all tasks for user and project id

```
SELECT DISTINCT task.*
    FROM user_task
    INNER JOIN task ON (task.id = user_task.task_id AND project_id = {project_id})
    WHERE user_task.user_id = {user_id}
```

With Eloquent :

```
DB::table('user_task')
            ->join('task', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('task.id', '=', 'user_task.task_id')->where('project_id', '=', {project_id})
        })
->where('user_task.user_id', '=', {user_id})
       ->get();
```

Comment: But what if I use MyISAM tabels?

Comment: It's the same, except you won't have contraints at DB level compared to InnoDB. Which change nothing there.

Comment: I thinks `foreign key` not working with MyISAM.. Also I need queries with Eloquent

Comment: foreign key is also a concept. You can add a **project_id** field in table **task** without any problem. I'm always working with miysam.

Comment: Updated with Eloquent syntaxe